# Cant scan QR codes with ZXing

Tags: android, zxing

I'm really new in Android Development and, like many others, I'm trying desperately to integrate ZXing into my project. I have to make a stand-alone QR scanning application for Android. (I'm using the 2.3.3 sdk).

I have to explain that I've already tried to find a solution to my problem by reading all the answers about the topic but I haven't suceed at all.

Here is what I've done:

1. I downloaded the ZXing 2.0 Release from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list)
2. Then, I added the assets, src and res to my project simply by dragging the files into my
   project.
3. I referenced the core.jar archive located in the "core" folder by right-clicking in my
   project > Build Path > Configure Build Path. I add ir as an External JAR.

This is a [image](http://i1191.photobucket.com/albums/z478/peperamirez89/Capture.jpg) to ilustrate.

1. In here, I was getting some errors in the ID's and some other resources. That was
   happening because I was referencing to que wrong R.java, so I solved that by changing "import com.google.zxing.client.android.R" to "import com.android.novaqr.R", which is my projects 
   package.
2. Then I added:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
   ```

and

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml

So now I have no errors in my code and here is where i need help: I need the phone to scan when I push a button. I've tried a lot of solutions that I saw on the other questions about this topic, but I haven't succeed.

I hope I'm clear with my question, if not, let me know and I'll try to be more specific

Any help will be really apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *strongly* discouraged from completely copying and pasting our app. It sounds like you're not experienced enough in Android to use it this way anyway.

Instead, you can use the app's scanning service by Intent, which is far easier and supported: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: I understand, but its not very comfortable for the user to obligate them to install both apps, I would rather prefer to do it inside my app

Comment: That doesn't make it OK to copy our app completely, which is what it appears you're doing as you don't have the expertise to selectively reuse parts. It doesn't sound like that is an option for you, if you can't get it to work. So: use Intents.

Comment: You realize this is likely infringing our trademark if you use the UI? This isn't a polite suggestion -- it's the developer telling you how you need to approach this.

Comment: "I understand, but its not very comfortable for the user to obligate them to install both apps, I would rather prefer to do it inside my app" - I think it is not very comfortable that you are forcing them to install your own copy of the the barcode scanning software, when they likely already have one that will undoubtedly work better, and be less prone to future errors installed on their device. Integrating different applications with Intents is fundamental to the Android OS. Literally the OS was designed to have applications work together in this manner. Overall it is best for the user.